# Directory.Deleteした直後のDirectory.CreateDirectoryがうまく動かない

Tags: c#, windows

ファイル操作のテストを行うプログラムを書いています。作業用のディレクトリが既に存在する場合は削除してから作り直そうと思い、次のように書きました。

```
if (Directory.Exists("foo"))
    Directory.Delete("foo", true);
Directory.CreateDirectory("foo");
```

ところがディレクトリ foo が既に存在している状態でこれを実行すると、ディレクトリが削除されるだけで再作成が行われません。この時も例外は出ていないようです。

同じようなコードがファイルに対しては問題なく動くのですが・・・。

```
if(File.Exists("bar"))
    File.Delete("bar");
File.WriteAllText("bar", "");
```

ディレクトリの再作成を行うにはどうすればよいでしょうか？
上記のような挙動になる理由も教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: 自環境で同じようにやってみましたが、再現できませんでした。ディレクトリが削除されて再作成されました。

Comment: 掲載されたコードは正しく動作し、権限設定で作成できないようにすると例外が発生しました。ただしExplorerでフォルダを開いている時に[フォルダが作成されない現象](http://sabotenbros.blogspot.jp/2015/09/systemiodirectorydelete.html)が報告されています。手元の環境では再現できなかったのですが、削除対象のファイルやフォルダをつかんでいる状態で削除しているなどの心当たりはあるでしょうか？

Comment: 最初に試したのは SoftPerfect RAM Disk で作成したRAMディスクで、ここでは今のところ確実に再現できています。が、SSDやHDDで試してみたら問題なく作成されました。また、FAT32でフォーマットしたUSBメモリでも時々発生するようです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Directory.Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/62t64db3(v=vs.100).aspx)のリファレンスに触れられていますが、対象のディレクトリを「エクスプローラーで開いている」と削除がすぐに行われない場合があります。

> 場合によっては、指定したディレクトリを Windows エクスプローラーで開いていると、Delete メソッドで削除できないことがあります。

[内部的](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,1486)に使用している[`RemoveDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365488.aspx)関数によるとこれはエクスプローラーに限った問題ではないようです。

> The RemoveDirectory function marks a directory for deletion on close. Therefore, the directory is not removed until the last handle to the directory is closed.

ですので`while`などを使用して実際に削除されるまで待機するのが良いかと思います。

Comment: 当該ディレクトリを開いていなければいいだろうと思っていたのですが、ProcessMonitorで見たらExplorerが後からハンドルを閉じていることが確認できたので、皆さんのご指摘の通りだったようです。長時間解放されない可能性も考えるとwhileでブロックするのは心配なので、10ms 後にもう一度確認してダメならエラーとすることにしました。（これでも手元の現象は十分解決できました）

Answer (score 3):

`Directory.Exists("foo")`でファイルの存在確認を行うとウィルス対策ソフトがスキャンを開始する場合があります。その場合、`Directory.Delete("foo", true)`はpgrhoさんが指摘されているように削除マークが付けられるだけで、実際の削除が遅延させられる可能性があります。
また`Directory.CreateDirectory("foo")`は[ドキュメント](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.100).aspx)にあるように

> 既存のディレクトリがある場合は、このメソッドは何も実行しません。

その上で、ウィルス対策ソフトのスキャンが完了すると削除マークに従い、ディレクトリが削除されます。

---

```
try {
    Directory.Delete("foo", true);
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) {}
Directory.CreateDirectory("foo");
```

と直接削除しにいった方がいいかもしれません。もしくはディレクトリ内のファイルを削除した方がいいです。

Answer (score 0):

最終手段として

IFileOperation::Deleteitems() API
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775767(v=vs.85).aspx

使うという手もあると思います。

試していませんが、↑は Win32 よりも上位の、Windows Shell (≒ Explorer.exe）の機能呼び出しを行うもの（のはず）なので、期待した動作を得られるのではないでしょうか。